# Who maintains babel now?

Tags: luatex, babel, ctan

Who manages `babel` now? It is said on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) that Johannes L. Braams is no longer active on this package. I'd like to contribute `babel`'s support for Russian in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: As far as I know J. Braams is still the maintainer but not very responsive. But you actually don't need contact: Simply put your ldf on CTAN and other will able to use it with `\usepackage[your_new_ldf_name]{babel}`. (You should naturally use a name which isn't already in use.).

Comment: note that ctan's view may differ from the latex project's view; what ctan sees is requests for updates and no responses.

Comment: @Ulrike: I need one more advice. My new code contains characters in unicode encoding. I am afraid that unicode might break some old compilers like emtex. So it is more safe to put new code into a separate file but it has its own drawback (I would prefer to have "2 in 1"). Which way would you recommend?

Comment: Last time I checked babel was a core part of LaTeX, so its supported by the LaTeX project.

Comment: Well neither old (emtex) nor newer 8-bit-compilers (pdftex) will have a problem to read an utf8 file - they will simply split the input in 8-bit-pieces. But the question is if the processing gives a sensible result e.g. when the main document uses e.g. `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}`. Also in general it is better to input non-ascii chars with the `^^`- (pdftex) or  `^^^^`-notation (xetex/luatex): then the file is pure ascii and there is less danger that the content is damaged when the file is changed and saved by an user.

Comment: @Ulrike, Thanks again. I appreciate your advice about `^^^^`-notation. I hope to post new russian.dtx for babel in few days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right contact for language related issues in LuaLaTeX might be Arthur Reutenauer who just took over development of Polyglossia. Polyglossia has not been ported to LuaLaTeX yet, but it should only be a matter of time until it gets ported.

(Of course you may also submit your babel files to CTAN as long as they don't break pdfLaTeX.)

Comment: Explains why the previous maintainer/author never replied to my e-mail :-)

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: what package do you mean: babel or polyglossia?

Comment: @Igor: Polyglossia.

Answer (score 16):

Babel is again maintained: http://www.tex-tipografia.com/babel_news.html .

Comment: But who does maintain babel? http://ctan.org/pkg/babel still is saying that Johannes L. Braams is no longer active on this package.

Comment: I guess that it is you who will support babel now. If so, please, update babel record on CTAN (ctan.org/pkg/babel). It would confirm that your person is approved by LaTeX team.

Comment: @Igor. Yes, it's me. For personal reasons I'll delayed the final decision about being considered the maintainer until November. For the moment, I'm "deputy maintainer" (see also http://www.latex-project.org/latex3.html and http://www.texdev.net/2012/08/03/babel-development-news/).

Comment: Thank you. I developed Russian LDF (http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/russian) which equally supports LaTeX and (PDF/Xe/Lua)LaTeX. Unfortunately, it was not included into the babel bundle because, I suppose, there was no active maintainer for babel at that time. Hopefully, this will change now :)

Comment: @Igor. Yes, this will change, because in the next release languages will be maintained and updated directly by their authors.

Comment: @JavierBezos The babel version of magyar.ldf (1.4j) conflicts with lots of popular packages. However, there is [version 1.5](http://ctan.org/pkg/magyar) which works perfectly. What is holding you back from including it in babel?

Comment: How can I contact @Javier Be­zos, the current maintainer of the babel package ? On his web-site he writes the any help on babel will be appreciated, I want to contribute but cannot find his email address.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov the above website has a form to contact him.